# Graph randomly not being plotted using achartengine android

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

I am using achartengine-1.1.0.jar. My code generates a line chart, which works most times (see below)

[image: http://imgur.com/Va3dRbf]

But sometimes a blank chart appears with the y and x-axis visible (as can be seen from the image). This happens rather randomly.

[image]

I've tried replicating the issue in various ways but still can't find the root cause. Till now it seem totally random.

Here's the snippet responsible for the graph:

```
String seriesTitle = "Alpha";
String seriesTitleB = "Beta";
String seriesTitleD = "Delta";
// create a new series of data
XYSeries series = new XYSeries(seriesTitle);
XYSeries seriesB = new XYSeries(seriesTitleB);
XYSeries seriesD = new XYSeries(seriesTitleD);
float x =1;
int c =0;
do{
   String s= alpha.getItems().get(c).toString();
   series.add((double)x, Double.parseDouble(s.substring(1, s.length()-1)));
   s= beta.getItems().get(c).toString();
   seriesB.add((double)x, Double.parseDouble(s.substring(1, s.length()-1)));
   s= delta.getItems().get(c).toString();
   seriesD.add((double)x, Double.parseDouble(s.substring(1, s.length()-1)));
   x++;
   c++;
}while(alpha.size() > c);

mDataset.addSeries(series);
mDataset.addSeries(seriesB);
mDataset.addSeries(seriesD);

// create a new renderer for the new series
XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
renderer.setColor(Color.argb(255, 238 , 89, 125));

// create a new renderer for the new series
XYSeriesRenderer rendererB = new XYSeriesRenderer();
rendererB.setColor(Color.argb(255, 29, 158, 225));

XYSeriesRenderer rendererD = new XYSeriesRenderer();
rendererD.setColor(Color.argb(255, 15, 122, 131));


mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(rendererB);
mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(rendererD);

mChartView.repaint();
```

Any idea what might be causing this erratic behaviour?

EDIT: @keshav this is where I am adding mChartView to my view

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mChartView == null) {
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chartProgress);
        mChartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, mDataset, mRenderer);
        // enable the chart click events
        mRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(10);
        mChartView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // handle the click event on the chart
                SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChartView.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
                if (seriesSelection == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(ProgressChart.this, "No chart element", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    // display information of the clicked point
                    Toast.makeText(
                            ProgressChart.this,
                            "Chart element in series index " + seriesSelection.getSeriesIndex()
                            + " data point index " + seriesSelection.getPointIndex() + " was clicked"
                            + " closest point value X=" + seriesSelection.getXValue() + ", Y="
                            + seriesSelection.getValue(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        layout.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        boolean enabled = mDataset.getSeriesCount() > 0;
    } else {
        mChartView.repaint();
    }
}
```

EDIT: Previously I did not mention that there are two linear layouts over each other.  One layout contains the chart (which is hidden at first).  The second layout contains date pickers.  The issue is happening when I touch an empty place in the datepickers' linear layout then when i press the button to change the linear layouts the blank chart happens. If I touch the datepickers only and not the empty spaces then the chart comes up fine.

Comment: is this wrapped in some try-catch section?

Comment: I did a try and catch and caught nothing.

Comment: Can you show where are you adding mChartView to your view ?

Comment: @keshav I have edited my post to answer your question.

Comment: First thing if your first half code is in onCreate(), then mChartView will be null there. So how are u doing this ? If I remove that mChartView I get graph every time. And second thing may be data values you are not getting every time .Here I m using random data.

Comment: The first half code is in onCreate() but inside an onClick method.  Secondly, I have tried using hard coded values and the issue still happened.